# Use of The Task Based Asynchronous Pattern regarding custom return objects

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

When my goal ( *perhaps I'm confused* ) is to actually return a complex class that has had a series of processes performed on it (a list of tasks not depicted here) 
Can I pass my custom object to the actual "DoSomethingAsync" method that starts the Tasks and can I manipulate their results INTO the object to return it to the caller SomethingAsync  so that its caller may then persist the data to disk (SQL or Whatever) or move it to the next step in my processes ?

All the potential interrupts or interference's to the async steps of the Tasks have me worried that.... for example Task1 while I harvest its results into the object may conflict with Task2's processes.

My tests have shown Task2's results being processed before I can harvest Task1's completed work.... but at the moment I'm concerned with correctly passing & populating a complex object, and this concern is probably regarding a different topic of how to correctly use multiple truly multithreaded tasks.  I expect answers in the vein of .. "run the asyncs to fill respective properties & don't try to fill your custom object IN the Async tasks" ,, but I had to ask, , assuredly I'm not the first to wonder about this.

I just reviewed the event-based & task-based,  of which I am familiar and can work with well.  But this day 5 of my TAP & TPL [*Task Parallel Library*] studies and I may be confusing myself with all of the odd details like CancellationToken, and Task Based Combinators as well as erroneously mixing TAP & TPL dynamics..  Anxiously awaiting the many down votes thanks

```
    public async Task<MyCustomObject> SomethingAsync()
{
    return await DoSomethingAsync(MyCustomObject);
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? I'm really unclear on what the problem is. Sounds like it's a simple bug but we need to see the code.

Comment: Actually due to the general nature of my inquiry no.. But I will gladly re phrase the question to structure it in its simplicity.   In my shown code I have MyCustomObject. Most examples showcase value types as the members of the Task object.  Is it possible and recommended Best Practice to attempt to pass and return and manipulate reference types in this construct Task<MyCustomObject> or just value types as the examples have shown... yet hint at the potential I have depicted of using Task<MyCustomObject> ?

Comment: Hm why would using reference types be a problem? Can you elaborate your concerns? Async and await have zero impact on ref types. They behave like they always do.